# Multiple added entities may have the same primary key, difficult mapping scenario

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Here is my scenario that I would like to map with Entity Framework, from the look of it I believe it is possible in SQL Server, so therefore it would be possible in Entity Framework right? So here goes,

**Scenario**

An operation is made up of team members. Two team members are special, they are the leader and co-leader. I would like these to be directly attached to the operation like this

```
public class Operation
{
    public int OperationId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Leader")]
    public int LeaderId { get; set; }
    public TeamMember Leader { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CoLeader")]
    public int CoLeaderId { get; set; }
    public TeamMember CoLeader { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Everybody in the operation
    /// </summary>
    public List<TeamMember> Team { get; set; }
}
```

A team member looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// A team member is specific for an operation, and is the linking table
/// between people and an operation
/// 
/// This table cannot be a composite key of OperationId and PersonId, 
/// as team members are created first and then the Person is assigned 
/// to be a team member.
/// </summary>
public class TeamMember
{
    public int TeamMemberId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Operation")]
    public int OperationId { get; set; }

    public Operation Operation { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Person")]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Now this almost works. If I remove the navigation property `Operation` from `TeamMember` I get the desired database. However with the navigation property I get the error:

```
Unable to determine the principal end of the 'TeamMember_Operation'
relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.
```

So now there is something a little dodgy, you could do this when querying `teamMember.Operation.Leader.Operation.Leader` and so on.... but you could actually do that in database query anyway, so I am thinking that isn't the reason for the error.

**Question**

Why would multiple entities be added with the same primary key, and how do I solve this.

(Would prefer Data Annotations if possible)

Comment: hey did you ever find a solution to this issue